# Format decimal number to 4 or 2 decimal places by removing zeros in the end

Tags: php

What I need to do is very simple: format number to 4 decimals (or 2 if it has 00 in the end)

I have numbers for example and their result:

- 15.2000  --->  15.20
- 15.6565  --->  15.6565

Let's say:`$number = 15.2000`

And I could use function

```
number_format($number, 4)
```

But then I would get a result: 15.2000 instead of 15.20

If I would use function

```
number_format($number, 2)
```

then I would get a result 15.65 instead of 15.6565

How do I make it to remove trailing zeros after decimals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trim two trailing zeros at the end of the string:

```
preg_replace('/00$/', '', $formatted_number)
```

See http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: Doesn't work as well as (how I understand it) the poster wants _at least_ two decimals. So `15.200` would still end up as `15.2`.

Comment: OP formats the number to 4 decimal places, so `15.200` would get formatted to `15.2000` *before* you apply this code.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. But; then we have the case of `15.4120`, that should be `15.412` I guess. If that's the case, do something like; `$decimals = strcspn(strrev($number), '.'); if ( $decimals < 2 ) { $number = number_format($number, 2); }`